# xsl:fo don't split word into 2 lines

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I want to stop splitting a generated word into two lines . Now I tried to use wrap-option="wrap" but nothing works.
I hope some can help me ;)

I use Saxon-HE,xslt 2.0

My xml-file:

```
<root>
     <out>
          invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
          <build>
               <name>John</name>
               <year>29</year>
               <address>London</address>
               <code>12345678902331234313123123123123123123</code>
          </build>At vero eos et    
     </out>
</root>
```

My xslt-file:

```
 <xsl:template match="out">
        <fo:block>
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="build">
        <fo:inline wrap-option="wrap" color="Red">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(./name,'-',./year,'-',./address,'+',./code)"/>
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>
```

My expected output is following:

```
Invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,sed diam voluptua
John-29-London+11231231231...
```

Output with my solution:

```
Invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,sed diam voluptua John-29
-London+123123..
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If those are the only templates in your stylesheet, text nodes are handled by the built-in template. You should not output text in such an uncontrolled way. If you add an empty template matching `text()` (as [I have told you already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29747176/1987598)), the text inside `build` appears on a single line.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
          <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page"
            page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm"
            margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="10mm"
            margin-left="25mm" margin-right="25mm">
            <fo:region-body
              margin-top="0mm" margin-bottom="15mm"
              margin-left="0mm" margin-right="0mm"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="10mm"/>
          </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">
          <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="out">
        <fo:block>
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="build">
        <fo:inline wrap-option="wrap" color="Red">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name,'-',year,'-',address,'+',code)"/>
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XSL-FO Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page"
                             page-height="297mm"
                             page-width="210mm"
                             margin-top="20mm"
                             margin-bottom="10mm"
                             margin-left="25mm"
                             margin-right="25mm">
         <fo:region-body margin-top="0mm"
                         margin-bottom="15mm"
                         margin-left="0mm"
                         margin-right="0mm"/>
         <fo:region-after extent="10mm"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>
            <fo:inline wrap-option="wrap" color="Red">John-29-London+12345678902331234313123123123123123123</fo:inline>
         </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**Rendered PDF Output**

> [image]

---

But the real question is, how to prevent text from wrapping if it is actually longer than one line, e.g. if the input looked like

```
<code>123456789023312343131231231248364387438463846837483643123123123</code>
```

then, a well-placed `keep` achieves what you want:

```
<xsl:template match="build">
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always" color="Red">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(./name,'-',./year,'-',./address,'+',./code)"/>
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

and then the line of text just overflows the page border

> [image]

and finally, the `keep-together`, but without the template matching `text()`:

> [image]

Comment: with fo:block wrap options work but then i have a line break after my output

Comment: @Franz I'm sorry, but I really don't know what you mean, which of my proposed solutions you are referring to, or which wrap option you are talking about, or what "output" exactly.

Comment: thank you with the keep-together attribute it works ;)